# Difference between inner and outer overloaded C++ operator

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I have the following code that will not compile, complaining that += operator does not exist. += operator is here declared outside of class A.

```
template < typename _T >
class A {
public:
    operator _T () const { return 42 ; }
};

template <typename _T >
A< _T > & operator += ( A< _T > & l, _T r ) { return l ; }


int main() {
    A< int > e, f ;
    e += f ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

However, if I implement the operator inside class A, code compiles and works :

```
template < typename _T >
class A {
public:
    operator _T () const { return 42 ; }

    A< _T > & operator += ( _T r ) { return *this ; }
};


int main() {
    A< int > e, f ;
    e += f ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

What is the difference between these two codes? Aren't they supposed to be equivalent?

This was compiled with gcc 4.4.7-4.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_T`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first example fails to compile because template argument deduction does not do any conversion.  With

```
template <typename _T >
A< _T > & operator += ( A< _T > & l, _T r ) { return l ; }
```

Both `l` and `r` contribute to determining what `_T` is.  When you do `e += f` then the compiler gets that `_T` must be `int` for `l` and it gets `r` must be `A<int>` since that is the type of `f`.  Since they do not match it fails to compile.

In the second code there is no template argument deduction going on.  The compiler knows what `_T` is from the instantiation of the class so all it needs to be able to do is convert what is passed to `r` to a `_T`.

---

I also suggest you get out of the habit of starting names with underscores.  There are a slew of rules about them and if you violate them then your program has undefined behavior since they are reserved for the implementation.  For more see [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 3):

The snarky short answer is, you used `_T` in user code, so your entire program is ill formed and no diagnostic required; identifiers consisting of a `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved to be used by the implementation.

In that sense both examples are exactly equivalent.

Ignoring that error, they are not identical.

The first is a non-member `template` `+=` operator.

The second is a non-template member `+=` of a template class that takes an implicit `this` as its first parameter.

These are very different things.  `template` function pattern matching does not do conversions (other than to-base); methods of `template` types *can* convert.

In the second case, the non-template `operator+=` is able to convert its second argument to be of type `_T`.  In the first case, the template `operator+=` won't try to convert while pattern matching types.

There is actually a 3rd possibility, which I often prefer:

```
template < class T >
struct A {
  operator T () const { return 42 ; }
  friend A& operator += ( A& l, T r ) { return l; (void)r; }
};
```

where we make a free `+=` as a friend.  This creates a non-template `+=` that takes two arguments, and hence is more symmetric.

Such non-template friends can be found via ADL.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f17cebdfda3b775).

As an aside, they also differ because a pointer to one can be stored in `A<_T>& (A<_T>::*)( _T )`, the other like `A<_T>& (*)(A<_T>&, _T)`.  These are not identical, nor can they be converted-between.

Comment: You got the first and second reversed.

Comment: @kund changed to tsrif and dnoces.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't they supposed to be equivalent ?

No, because in the first example, `_T` is a template [function parameter which gets deduced](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call), while in the second example it is already known.

Imagine the second example being expanded by the compiler:

```
template <>
class A_int {
public:
    operator int () const { return 42 ; }

    A< int > & operator += ( int r ) { return *this ; }
};
```

---

g++ 7.0 gives a good error message explaining why the deduction fails:

```
deduced conflicting types for parameter '_T' ('int' and 'A<int>')
```

---

A possible solution/workaround is adding an extra template parameter:

```
template <typename _T, typename _U>
A< _T > & operator += ( A< _T > & l, _U r ) { return l ; }
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Do8EvANFZd9tnKeu)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky. In your second case, your operator is a member function of the class template `A`, not a template itself. When you call `e += f`, a match is found as `A<int>::operator += (int)`, which already exists inside `A<int>`. There is an implicit conversion from `A<int>` to `int`, so this overload is valid.

In your first case, the operator is a template: the compiler tries to instanciate it by deducing the argument `_T` from the call site alone. Template argument deduction does not consider user-defined conversions, so the deduction fails.

The solution is to prevent the second parameter from participating in deduction, by making use of a non-deducible context such as an additional indirection through a template:

```
template <class T>
struct NonDeduced_ { using type = T; }

template <class T>
using NonDeduced = typename NonDeduced_<T>::type;

template <typename _T >
A< _T > & operator += ( A< _T > & l, NonDeduced<_T> r ) { return l ; }
```

Then only the first parameter participates in deduction, which succeeds, *then* the deduced `_T` is used to see if the second parameter has viable conversions.